# Domain Driven Design - Inheritance guidance

Tags: inheritance, domain-driven-design, domain-model

Im starting to learn Domain-Driven-Design, and need some guidance when it comes to inheritance.

I have the following class representing an employee:

```
public class Employee
{
    public Guid EmployeeID { get; }

    public String Firstname { get; }

    public String Lastname { get; }

    // Constructor
    private Employee(Guid employeeID, String firstname, String lastname)
    {
        EmployeeID = employeeID;
        Firstname = firstname;
        Lastname = lastname;
    }

    // Factory
    public static Create(Guid employeeID, String firstname, String lastname)
    {
        return new Employee(employeeID, firstname, lastname)
    }

}
```

**THE PROBLEM**

The employee can also be an owner of a company, and my question is how to build the CompanyOwner-class? Whats the recommended way to implement this?

**Option 1: Inherit Employee-class**

The company owner is an employee, so it feels like one way could be to inherit Employee.

*However, this means that the properties EmployeeID, Firstname and Lastname must change to have protected setters in Employee-class. Is that ok in DDD?*

```
public class CompanyOwner : Employee
{
    // ID for the owner (primary key in database)
    public Guid CompanyOwnerID { get; }

    // Constructor
    private CompanyOwner(Guid companyOwnerID, Guid employeeID, String firstName, String lastName)
    {
        CompanyOwnerID = companyOwnerID;        
        EmployeeID = employeeID;        
        Firstname = firstname;
        Lastname = lastname;
    }

    // Factory        
    public static CompanyOwner Create(Guid companyOwnerID, Guid employeeID, String firstname, String lastname)
    {
        return new CompanyOwner(companyOwnerID, employeeID, firstname, lastname);
    }

}
```

**Option 2: Separate property for employee info**

*By doing this the Employee-factory method can be called. But then I have to access it via MyOwner.EmployeeInfo.Firstname, it would be cleaner with just MyOwner.Firstname*

```
    public class CompanyOwner
    {
        // Unique ID for the owner (primary key)
        public Guid CompanyOwnerID { get; }

        // Employee info
        public Employee EmployeeInfo { get; }
       
        // Constructor
        private CompanyOwner(Guid companyOwnerID, Guid employeeID, String firstName, String lastName)
        {
            CompanyOwnerID = companyOwnerID;

            // Calling factory-method of Employee-class to set employee-info
            EmployeeInfo = Employee.Create(employeeID, firstName, lastName);
        }

        // Factory        
        public static CompanyOwner Create(Guid companyOwnerID, Guid employeeID, String firstname, String lastname)
        {
            return new CompanyOwner(companyOwnerID, employeeID, firstname, lastname);
        }

    }
```

**Option 3: Skip CompanyOwner-class and use IsOwner-property in Employee-class instead**

*This is actually not an option in my case, since the employee can be owner for multiple companies, and also CompanyOwnerID (primary key for the owner) does not fit in the Employee-class*

```
public class Employee
{
    public Guid EmployeeID { get; }

    public String Firstname { get; }

    public String Lastname { get; }

    public Boolean IsOwner { get; }

    // Constructor
    private Employee(Guid employeeID, String firstname, String lastname, Boolean isOwner)
    {
        EmployeeID = employeeID;
        Firstname = firstname;
        Lastname = lastname;
        IsOwner = isOwner;
    }

    // Factory
    public static Create(Guid employeeID, String firstname, String lastname, Boolean isOwner)
    {
        return new Employee(employeeID, firstname, lastname, isOwner)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking: your design is broken. You do not ahve an employee class that represents a person - employee, owner, whatever are ROLES an entity (person, legal entity actually in case of shareholder) has. They may be temporary, they may change over time (employee coming, terminating, coming back). IsOwner is not necessarily a good representation because if refers to an on/off relationship that can change over time, AND is ignoring percentages.

So, you have an entity (OOP term) "Entity" with a subclass NaturalEntity (Person). Entity has ROLES (m:n) and one of the roles is - Employee. You CAN simplify that - but if you do that (like you did) you run into all kinds of problems (as, again, you did) as you are not modelling natural entities.

And yes, doing it properly makes things a LOT more complex in many scenarios - but then it is stable. So, your simplifications have merit for simplified cases. Which one you choose, then, depends on exact needs - without context it is hard to answer. And context is the exact needs of the application. Which, word of warning, may change over time - so unless it gets really complex, it is very often better to do it right because the alternative is being stuck when the needs change.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. 
If I understand correct, you suggest to have two classes, "Person" and "Entity", where "Enitity" can have one or more roles.

Where do we then place for example "Percentages" and other properties that are specific properties only for one of the roles? If you can provide a short example in code it would help a lot

Comment: yeah. Note that I do down the line and say Entity is a base class for NaturalEntity (which is a person) OR (possibly) LEgalEntity (company). Also handles long term subcontractors, owners may be another company

Comment: There is no short example, sorry. There is a gbook - the Data Model Resource Book, Volume 1 - which goes over this in detail OVER AROUND 150 PAGES. Ok, only a smaller part is about this part - but these relationships, when modelled properly, are complex and people do not do examples, they write books about it. I would strongly suggest getting a copy of that - it is not from a programming, but from a data / SQL point of view but deals with all of that ins a VERY interesting amount of detail.

Comment: For a more general example where ClassB inherit ClassA, whats the recommended way for ClassB to set the properties of ClassA when ClassA, according to the principle of "domain driven design", only should have private/no setters for its properties? Or should inheritance totaly be avoided when it comes to domain driven designs?